# Quadratic variation of $ X_t = t W_t $

Tags: brownian-motion, law-of-large-numbers, quadratic-variation

> Let $W = \{W_t : t \geq 0\}$ be the standard Brownian motion and consider
>   $$X_t=t W_t$$
>   Show that the quadratic variation of $X_t$ is $\frac{t^3}{3}$
>
> I know this question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/816185/quadratic-variation-of-x-t-tb-t) but I would like to do it by definition, ie, i would like to show that
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(\Delta X_{t_i})^2\stackrel{L^2}{=}\frac{t^3}{3}, $$
>   $\text{ with } \ \Delta X_{t_i}=X_{t_i}-X_{t_{i-1}} \text{ and } t_{i}=\frac{t}{n}i$

My Attempt: I have shown that $\Delta X_{t_i} \sim \mathcal{N}(0,(\frac{t}{n})^3(i^2+i-1))$ and I was thinking about applying the LLN but I cannot do it since the variance has a term which is not constant in $i$.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is to be understood in mean-square or $L^2$ sense. Use the independence of the increments and properties of the Gaussian distribution in order to show that $E[(\sum_i(\Delta X_i)^2-t^3/3)^2]$ converges to zero.

**Edit (additional details):**

First show that $E[(\sum_i(\Delta X_i)^2]\to t^3/3$. Using your result that $\Delta X_i\sim\mathcal{N}(0,\sigma_i^2)$ with $\sigma_i^2=(t/n)^3(i^2+i-1)$, we obtain as $n\to\infty$

$$ E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(\Delta X_i)^2\right]=\sum_{i=1}^n E\left[(\Delta X_i)^2\right] = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i^2= \frac{t^3}{n^3}\frac{n^3+3n^2-n}{3}=\frac{t^3}{3}+O(1/n)\to \frac{t^3}{3}.$$
Therefore, because of independence, as $n\to\infty$
$$E\left[\left(\sum_{i=1}^n(\Delta X_i)^2-t^3/3\right)^2\right]=\text{Var}\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(\Delta X_i)^2\right]+O(1/n^2)=\sum_{i=1}^n\text{Var}\left[(\Delta X_i)^2\right]+O(1/n^2)\\=2\sum_{i=1}^n\sigma_i^4+O(1/n^2)=\frac{2t^6}{n^6}\frac{n^5+5n^4+5n^3-5n^2-n}{5}+O(1/n^2)=O(1/n)\to 0.$$
This shows that the $L^2$ limit of the sum of quadratic increments is equal to $t^3/3$.

Comment: maybe I should rephrase the problem but in fact I'm intended to find the quadratic variation of that process without knowing a priori that it is $\frac{t^3}{3}$.

Comment: Assuming that you do not know the limit, first compute the expectation of the sum of quadratic increments. Then show that the variance goes to zero.

Comment: I know how to show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\mathbb{E}[\sum_{i=1}^n (\Delta X_{t_i})^2 ] = \frac{t^3}{3}$$ but then I don't know how to conclude that the quadratic variation is $\frac{t^3}{3} $

Comment: I added some additional details. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation! I guess the worst part was knowing by heart the sums $$\sum_{i=1}^n i^k\text{ for } k=2,3,4,5$$

Comment: Actually you do not need the full expression. You only need to argue that the leading order term is $O(n^{k+1})$.